# 'The given path's format is not supported' when attaching with email

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I am trying to attach some pdf document when sending email but I get above error when I try to attach.

code I am using is:

```
Attachment a = new Attachment("External_path", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

External_Path points to pdf on external website and can confirm it exists. I have also tried chaing MediaTypeNames to `'MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf'` but that didn't work either.

Has someone experienced same problem while attaching attachments to an email?

Comment: please show real value of `external path`

Comment: @DrKoch: its quite a sensitive document but i'll try to give you some dummy path replicating all the spaces as in the path: ````https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/1/4/A B(XYZ) Policy 2015.pdf```` (Can spaces in the path be a problem?)

Comment: Attachments can only be from the *local* file system.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Attachment` says, the constructor must be called with a *file path*. What you use is an URL.

You must download the document to a local (temporary) file and read it from there.

Comment: Ok, i am now trying with file from my local machine but i get ````'(((System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase)(data)).ContentStream).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'```` error.